# Cucumber and Maven configuration

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I'm using a hybrid framework with cucumber, java, testNG and Maven.
I want to run a piece of code after getting result of each scenario(PASSED/FAIL). I have added the code in @AfterMethod and it working fine for TestNG but not for Maven because maven is not invoking afterMethod.

Then I tried using @After hook by cucumber. But it runs the code before getting actual scenario result.
I have also used (alwaysRun=true) but still not working for me
Can someone guide what can be done in this case.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some representative code snippets